# outline issue for focus/active inputs

Tags: html, css, border, outline

I have an issue concerning an outline effect for inputs in a log in form :

I try to do an icloud clone and I like the outline effect in blue when inputs are actives and focus.
I also don't want any effect due to borders when manipulating inputs so I set `border: none;`.

The issue I'm having is when I did the effect with simple CSS, the second input (password) hover the outline of the first (email). I tried to play with margin and padding but I didn't succeed to resolve it...

```css
.email-input,
.pass-input {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  outline: 1px solid rgb(155, 154, 154);
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.email-input:active,
.email-input:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: 2px solid #0070c9;
}

.pass-input:active,
.pass-input:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: 2px solid #0070c9;
}

.email-input {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.pass-input {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-1">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <img src="../Assets/login-logo.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="login-title">
    <p class="login-text">
      Se connecter avec un identifiant
    </p>
  </div>
  <form action="#" class="main-form">
    <div class="login-form">
      <span>
            <input id="username" class="email-input" type="email" placeholder="Identifiant" required="">
          </span>
      <span>
            <input id="password" class="pass-input" type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" required="">
            <button id="submit" class="fal fa-arrow-circle-right"></button>
          </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**And some screenshots :**

[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEYg4.png)

[The wished result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miul4.png) for the second input

Tried :

- margin top and bottom for both inputs, but I don't like the result. I would like a seamless connexion between both.
- border-top:none; //for the pass-input

I think the ideal would be to have a solution for like an outline-top:none; for the second input. But I didn't know it and didn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is related the the second input being rendered above the first, so the first input's outline is rendered under the second input.

To fix this, assign a default `z-index` value to the inputs, and when focused, set the focused element's `z-index` to a higher value than that of the other element so it's rendered above.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/tLo1w0f4/2/

*(I also added `outline-offset` to your styling to make sure the outline doesn't move when switching inputs. You would probably need this later)*

Comment: thank you so much ! That is what i was looking for. I started to look into properties of <outline-offset> but i didn't gave it enough attention..
That is very clear and very helpful

Thanks again !